# How to play HTML5 video play in webpage(inline) in iOS 10+

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, youtube

Just like **youtube** does. Open **youtube.com in safari or chrome browser**. It plays the video inline (Its doesnt goes fullscreen automatically). 
I am also using HTML5 video player in my website. But it **goes to native player in full screen.** 
I tried these attributes in video tag
 "webkit-playsinline" , "playsinline" , controlslist="nodownload"

Any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example from the webkit online information (https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/):

```js
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="image.mp4">
  <source src="image.webm" onerror="fallback(parentNode)">
  <img src="image.gif">
</video>
```